# PowerCLI create a root folder under Datastore Tab

Tags: directory, powercli

When running:
New-Folder -Name myFolder -Location (Get-Folder -NoRecursion)

it creates a root folder under "Hosts and clusters"...  How do I create a root folder under the Datastores Tab?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you'll need to reference the hidden (from UI) 'datastore' folder object. You can do this with the following code:

```
New-Folder -Name myFolder -Location (Get-Folder -Name datastore)
```

Similarly, you can do the same thing when you need to create Host or Network folders.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Interesting it did the same thing, it placed the newly created folder under the existing datacenter....

Comment: so instead of having... vcenterserver --> myFolder --> Datacenter,  it shows as: vcenterserver --> Datacenter --> myFolder, from the web client if I right click on the top most "vcenter-server-name" and choose New folder it will creates it right below the server, however when I run the command it puts it under the first datacenter instead...

Comment: Update: maybe just my lack of experience with vmware... I went and deleted my only datacenter & all the hidden folders were gone with it... So I guess the datacenter is the root for the other folders...

Comment: with all this: I'll rephrase the question, in a newly created vcenterserver where there are no "hidden" folders yet, when you go to the Storage tab, it allows you to create a folder, can you do the same using a command? ty